How long does it take for Facebook Graph API data to stabilize? (Regarding API caching)
I use Facebook Graph API to get my ads insights. However, I notice small discrepancies (a few people or a few dozen) when I fetch the data for the previous day at different times. This is likely due to Facebook API caching. I couldn't find information on how long it takes for these data to stabilize (for example, GA4 states that data stabilizes after 48 hours).
Could anyone provide some details on this ? Thanks.
I couldn't find specific time range.
